# Using Nginx with Nextcloud/Website/Paperwork parallel

Tags: php, nginx, web, nginx-location, nextcloud

I am trying to run Nextcloud,a Homepage and Paperwork under different locations, but can't figure out how to configure my nginx-config correctly.

My working tree looks like this:

> /var/www/
>   |-> website
>   |-> nextcloud
>   |-> paperwork

My Homepage is reachable through web.domain.com and my Nextcloud ist reachable with cloud.domain.com.
Now i want to get Paperwork to be reachable under web.domain.com/notes.
The index.php of Paperwork lies in the subfolder "paperwork/frontend/public".

This is my attemp to solve this (without the whole ssl and the cloud part):

```
server{
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name web.domain.com;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/debug.log debug;

    root /var/www/website;
    location / {
    index index.php index.html;
    }

    location /notes {
            alias /var/www/paperwork/frontend/public;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/index.php;
    }

    location ~ /(nextcloud|backups) {
            deny all;
            return 403;
    }
    location ^~ /nextcloud/ {
            deny all;
            return 402;
    }
    location ^~ /nextcloud/ {
            deny all;
            return 402;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            alias /var/www/paperwork/frontend/public;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;

            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME 
            $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;

    }
}
```

I tried out a lot different solutions but i eather get an 404 because he is using the wrong directory and can't find /var/www/notes/index.php (or similar errors) or nginx is returning me just the index.php as a file-download.

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested location blocks for a cleaner solution. Note the `^~` modifier to avoid any ambiguity. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.

Try:

```
location ^~ /notes {
    alias /var/www/paperwork/frontend/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /notes/index.php last; }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
}
```

There is a [long standing bug](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97) regarding the use of `alias` with `try_files`. See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

Include `fastcgi_params` before using the `fastcgi_param` directive, as it may silently overwrite your parameters.

Comment: Just tried it and its working. You are aweseome.Thx!